# How to save images with an object in Play framework 2.0 + java + mysql

Tags: playframework-2.0

As the tittle.How the simple way to save images with an object and display them?

Sry if my question is ugly. i'm new with Play framework :(

Comment: You need to write at least what did you try and what do you understand by save with an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upload just save the image preferably in the file system (not directly in the app) or even in some external CDN/cloud storage and then save its path in DB as a common String.

So you can use for an example some lightweight HTTP server for serving the files or even use Play's streaming possibilities as described [in the doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaStream) - in section `Serving files`.

Of course if you'll store the file in external service like CDN, all you need to do is place absolute path in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For file uploads with play and java check:
    http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload

and for saving that file in a DB check:
http://cyberasylum.janithw.com/saving-files-to-mysql-databases-using-java/

Comment: Thanks Javkob. It so nice